# Gallery images overflow to left

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a carousel - gallery viewer for my website and I have problems with the elements in it.
The images at the bottom are overflowing but only to the left. I have set the overflow property to hidden but it does not seem to work in this side.
In addition, the images are not affected by the property margin-right for some reason, only by margin left.

Here is a demo of the image viewer: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XbgdWo

This is the code I am using for the image items. I use margin-right to show it is not working properly.

```
.slider-item img {
width: 100%;
margin-left: 5px;
margin-right: 5px;
overflow: hidden;
@include transition('all .2s ease-in-out'); }

.slider-item:hover {
img { @include transform(scale(1.1)); } }
```

I would really appreciate if you could have a look at it. I have no idea what to do to fix it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried setting a `max-width` on `div.slick-track`?

Comment: Yeah, I have. It does not change anything. I have also tried that property in `.slider-item` or `slick-slide` :c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to have the `overflow:hidden` on the image itself, just the containing element - which you have.

The effect you are after works fine, you just have an issue with `margin` - you have put it on the img when it should but on the parent (`.slick-slide`).

I have forked your [codepen here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QbgNJJ) and fixed the issue, I added a red background to the img container so you can see the changes, the code is still messy but it gets the job done. I will continue to refine the code in the same pen.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked. I will reorganize the code to look nicer.

Comment: Glad that fixed it! I will leave it to you to clean up, but there are quite a few lines you can remove or condense to optimise the SCSS.

Answer (score 0):

Your body has 80 percent of width.

First of all, add the following CSS to the body to make it appear properly.

```css
body {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, I changed it. Although I am only using this as a template right now, to merge it later with the rest of the website with my partner.